# MS word picture format recolor with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

how to change color with vba for picture inlineshape
code

```
Public Function imagetransform()
    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
      If singleLine.range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        Dim shp4d1 As InlineShape
        Set shp4d1 = singleLine.range.InlineShapes(1)
        shp4d1.Select
        End If 
  Next singleLine
End Function
```

[image]

how to achieve this with vba macro?

Comment: Not all of the UI functionality gets added to the object model. This is one of the functions that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all functionality available in the Word object model which is available on the ribbon via Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI). The gallery control provides a basic functionality which doesn't allow selecting the required item programmatically. However, you may try to use Windows API (Accessibility API) to automate the UI for that.